# ssh hangs after authentication succedded

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04

ssh hangs after authentication succeeded displayed by using very very very verbose. Other users can log in without any problem. root login from my IP still works.

auth.log on the server says a session is open for me, but on my client side, it hangs indefinitely.

I suppose there is something wrong on my client workstation, not on the server.

I did login many times yesterday, but I doubt anti-dos measure is activated against my user account.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: My friend has the similar problem from the change in configuration in /etc/sshd_config. To solve this problem, he went on site to correct it. I'm not sure if you have any policy or configuration change or not.

Comment: try using ```ssh <hostname> /bin/sh```.  Once you've authenticated, try typing a command like ```ls``` and see if you get any output.  If so, your session may be hanging on something in one of your login scripts.  If not, then it's likely not reaching the point where scripts are getting executed.  You won't actually see a system prompt if you connect this way, but things like ```vi``` and ```mv``` will still work, so if it does turn out to be login scripts, mv them to a temporary location and try logging in again.  You can also use ```ssh -vvv <hostname>``` to identify where it's hanging.

Comment: This morning the other users couldn't login either. But we restarted, then everyone can login now.